# Add rounded color border to pdfpcell in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I m using this code to give border radius to my pdfpcell

```
cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
cell.CellEvent = new RoundedBorder();
Color color2 = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2AB1C3"));
cell.BorderColor = new Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2AB1C3"));
cell.BorderWidth = 2f;
```

and the function RoundedBorder

```
public class RoundedBorder : IPdfPCellEvent
{  
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas)

 PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
cb.RoundRectangle(
     rect.Left + 1.5f,
     rect.Bottom + 1.5f,
     rect.Width - 3,
     rect.Height - 3, 4
   );
cb.Stroke();
}
 }
```

I got rounded border but it is coming with black color and i want to give my custom color border to rounded radius

Can anyone help me on this ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are configuring the `PdfPCell` to have no border (`cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER`), setting border properties like border width and color won't have any effect.

You have to define the color of the stroke operation in your cell event, e.g. for a red border:

```
cb.SetRGBColorStroke(255, 0, 0);
cb.RoundRectangle(
 rect.Left + 1.5f,
 rect.Bottom + 1.5f,
 rect.Width - 3,
 rect.Height - 3, 4
);
cb.Stroke();
```

Comment: Can i also give border to table? I want to create a table with rounded border and in that table i want to insert another table (nesting table) with 3 cells?

Comment: There's a `PdfPTableEvent` that you can use in a similar way as the `PdfPCellEvent`. Have a look at [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=96). It paints a background with rounded corners for a table. To get a border instead, just replace fill operations by stroke operations.